# How can I create a .htaccess on localhost (Appserv)

Tags: php, .htaccess, localhost

I've tried too many example but I didn't succeed on rewrite rules.

This is what want:

This adress: `localhost/admin/page.php?id=25`
to turn into: `localhost/admin/settings`

"settings" is a variable in page.php

Can you please help me?

Comment: You might want to look into how **mod_rewrite** works. I quickly read through this guide: https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204643270/using-htaccess-rewrite-rules which looked quite easy to understand

Comment: @chriszo111 there is nothing there about what I asked

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following?

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule    ^admin/settings/?$  admin/page.php?id=25 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Where will I use the variable that contains "settings" value?

Comment: how would you like it to work? From what I gathered from the question, you wanted `localhost/admin/settings` to take you to `localhost/admin/page.php?id=25` in your example there is no variable values apart from the `?id=25`

Comment: I want exactly opposite you wrote. localhost/admin/page.php?id=25 to => localhost/admin/settings

Comment: But what would be the point in this? whenever you would create a link to say `localhost/admin/page.php?id=25` you would instead make the link `localhost/admin/settings` instead. The point of rewrites is to make URL's easier to read and remember. Maybe I am not understanding the big picture

Comment: I have thousands of entries in my db that I select and print in page.php. Instead of page.php?id=xx , I want to use link format that I wrote. It will be easier for users to use the site.

Comment: So does the `id=25` correspond to settings?

Comment: or would you want something like `/settings25`

Comment: /settings25 also will work but like I said, "settings" value will come from a variable from the page.php

Comment: So what has the 25 got to do with this? you want a variable in the `page.php` script to rename the `settings` part?

Comment: 25 is a just an example to refers id of entry's database id. I just want to make same seo for those links.

Comment: as far as I am aware, you can only rewrite one way... what you want to do is load a page, get a variable and use that in the URL which I do not know how to do if it can be done at all

Comment: @VitoAndolini - Which of the URL's do you want to expose in links etc? Is it `admin/settings` or is it `admin/page.php?id=25`? If it is `admin/settings`, then this answer does what you want.

Comment: @VitoAndolini - If you want to expose `admin/page.php?id=25`, then I don't really get your issue, since you can handle that in your `page.php`-file instead of in the htaccess.